# When setting a local scale to an instantiated gameObject, it loses material

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I'm instantiating a gameObject from prefab, and I want to set local scale using code, but when I'm setting transform.localScale to the gameObject then it loses material and becomes black.

```
public GameObject ballObject;    

 public GameObject GetBall(Ball ball)
     {
         GameObject gameObject = Instantiate(ballObject, ball.position, Quaternion.identity);
         gameObject.transform.localScale = ball.scale; // actually, this line destroys the material
         gameObject.tag = Constants.ballTag;

         return gameObject;
     }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Odd. are you sure its not just because the nose in the middle is black, so it comes black too?

Comment: when you say it loses its material is it actually showing as gone in the inspector?, also is this a model you have imported? if so check the normals on it as the when setting the scale it might be inverting them

Comment: Thanks akaBase, that was model issue, I was setting Vector2 instead of Vector3.

Comment: can you please check the value of the scale in ```Debug.Log()``` and make sure that no axis is set to zero in scakl value.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like 'ball.scale' may have a value of zero in one axis, which is flattening the object, which can mess with the appearance in this way.

Check what the scale values are for the incoming object.